# Get characters before last space in string

Tags: javascript, string

Is there a way to obtain all characters that are after the last space in a string?

Examples:

```
"I'm going out today".
```

I should get `"today"`.

```
"Your message is too large".
```

I should get `"large"`.

Comment: this almost sounds like homework ;)

Comment: @JensBerfenfeldt It's an easy thing to do but it's common to have to do it.

Comment: After or before the last space?

Comment: @dystroy Never said it wasn't easy, just saying that it sounds alot like something someone new might get asked to do as an assignment :)
May be my lack of coffee but In what scenarios would you use this outside of assignment purposes?

Comment: @JensB one example would be doing something like a predictive type, resetting the logic on every space user types in. Also so what if it's an assignment, it is a helpful question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do

```
var sentence = "Your message is too large";
var lastWord = sentence.split(' ').pop()
```

Result : `"large"`

Or with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) :

```
var lastWord = sentence.match(/\S*$/)[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var x = "Your message is too large";

function getLastWord(str){
    return str.substr(str.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
}

alert(getLastWord(x)); // output: large

// passing direct string
getLastWord("Your message is too large"); // output: large
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
    var str="I'm going out today";
    var s=str.split(' ');
    var last_word=s[s.length-1];
```

Answer (score 3):

use string.lastIndexOf():

```
var text = "I'm going out today";
var lastIndex = text.lastIndexOf(" ");
var result = '';
if (lastIndex > -1) {
    result = text.substr(lastIndex+1);
}
else {
    result = text;
}
```

UPDATE: Comment edited to add check if there's no space in the string.

Comment: Incidentally the `+1` also makes sure it still works if there are no spaces in the string :)

Comment: I didn't mean that you have to add a condition, the previous code was fine.